# Am I showing off?

Tags: salat, sin, doubts

Whenever I pray in front of someone or I tell someone about what dua I have recited or something related to my religion, I always have this doubt "am I showing off?", "is this a sin?". Even if I am normally talking about Islam, I always have this doubt. Does it count as showing off? How do I avoid this?